# why i can't to use this code f.collection_select

Tags: collection-select

I would like to replace this line code:

from:

```
f.collection_select(:status, Status.all, :id,  :name
```

to:

```
f.collection_select(:status, [{id: 1, name: "status1"}, {id: 2, name: "status2"}], :id,  :name
```

But i got error:

> undefined method `name' for {:id=>1, :name=>"status1"}:Hash

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select(:status, [['status1', 1], ['status1', 2]] ) %>
```